# Modified triangle inequality for squared two norm

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'd like to prove the following:

$$\lVert x - y \rVert^2 - \lVert z - y \rVert^2 \leq \lVert x - z \rVert^2$$

for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I've seen the result used in a few places, but I can't justify it to myself.

Without the squares, it's a simple application of the triangle inequality to show

$$\lVert x - y \rVert - \lVert z - y \rVert = \lVert x - z + z - y \rVert - \lVert z - y \rVert \leq \lVert x - z \rVert$$

Comment: Is this even true? What if $x,y,z$ are vectors from the orogin to the vertices of an obtuse triangle?

Answer (score 2):

It is false. Take the triangle $xyz$, where $$\|x-y\|=1.5,\|y-z\|=\|x-z\|=1$$ then
$$\lVert x - y \rVert^2=2.25,\lVert z - y \rVert^2=1,\lVert x - z \rVert^2=1$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I misunderstood the framing of the problem where I saw it used.